# In SAS --Summing binary is producing Binary Results

Tags: sas

I am trying to convert a  categorical variable (Product) in binary and then want to know how many products per customer.

data is in the following format:

```
ID Product 
C1 A
C1 B
C2 A
C3 B
C4 A
```

The code I am using for converting category to binary

```
IF PRODUCT="A" THEN PROD_A =1 ; ELSE PROD_A=0;
IF PRODUCT="B" THEN PROD_B =1 ; ELSE PROD_B=0;
TOT_PROD = SUM(PROD_A, PROD_B);
```

But when I count no. of product it gives me '1' for all customer and I am expecting 1 or 2.

I have tried

```
TOT_PROD = PROD_A + PROD_B;
```

but I get the same results

Answer (score 4):

This is all inside one datastep, correct? If so you're processing only one line at a time. For each individual line the only possible values for PROD_A and PROD_B are one or zero. You need an aggregate function. For example, if your dataset is named `PRODUCTS`:

```
DATA X;
SET PRODUCTS;
IF PRODUCT="A" THEN PROD_A = 1 ; ELSE PROD_A=0;
IF PRODUCT="B" THEN PROD_B = 1 ; ELSE PROD_B=0;
TOT_PROD = SUM(PROD_A, PROD_B);
RUN;
```

(`TOT_PROD` will always be equal to 1 in `X`, but never mind for now).

Now sum them up:

```
proc sql;
create table prod_totals as
select product, sum(tot_prod) as total_products
from x
group by product;
quit;
```

More simply just skip the data step:

```
proc sql;
create table prod_totals as
select product, count(*) as total_products
from products
group by product;
quit;
```

Or use `PROC SUMMARIZE` or `PROC MEANS` instead of `PROC SQL`.

Comment: This is correct.  If you are coming from another programming language, think of the data step as the inner portion of a FOR loop operating over the records in your data.  You cannot (easily) do operations across all records as you are only accessing them 1 at a time.

Answer (score 0):

To do this in the data step, you need `retain`.  Make sure you've sorted the dataset `by id` first.

```
data prod_totals;
set products;
by ID;
retain prod_a prod_b;
if first.id then do;    *initialize to zero for each new ID;
  prod_a=0; prod_b=0;
end;
if product='A' then prod_a=1;      *set to 1 for each one found;
else if product='B' then prod_b=1;
if last.id then do;                *for last record in each ID, output and sum total;
  total_products=sum(prod_a,prod_b);
  output;
end;
keep id prod_a prod_b total_products;
run;
```

Comment: I'd add... just be sure the dataset is ordered by ID. The BY clause (together with FIRST and LAST) allows to handle aggregation respecting the current physical order of rows. Another gotcha for SAS newbies.

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed you only want 1 record output per id.

In the solutions below I have employed the [DOW-Loop](http://analytics.ncsu.edu/sesug/2010/BB13.Dorfman.pdf) (DO-Whitlock).

If you wanted `prod_a` and `prod_b` just to help with the totals and if they're not required in the output, then you could use something like:

```
data want;
  do until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    tot_prod=sum(tot_prod,product='A',product='B');
  end;
run;
```

If you need `prod_a` and `prod_b` in the output, then you could use:

```
data want;
  do until(last.id);
    set have;
    by id;
    prod_a=(product='A');
    prod_b=(product='B');
    tot_prod=sum(tot_prod,prod_a,prod_b);
  end;
run;
```

In both data steps the last product per id will be output along with the other variables and in the case of the 2nd data step example the last prod_a & prod_b per id will also be output.